# Can Polaris Office be installed on Ubuntu 18.04.4?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

Looking to transfer my Win7 computer over to Ubuntu.  Everything good so far, however Polaris Office does not seem to have a Linux version.  I prefer to keep using Polaris Office because I have files saved on the cloud server that I access with Polaris on other devices.  Is there a process that would let me do this?

Comment: If you really want to keep polaris, best bet right now seems to have a windows install in virtualbox.  Could try using wine, but don't know if it will work.  Can try looking at alternatives to polaris that will work on all systems.  Not best news but some programs just don't work except on windows.  Maybe someone else will know more.

Comment: @crip659, your comment is The Answer. There is no Linux version, period. The OP must make a decision: Complexity and a learning curve to keep Polaris, or migrating to a new application.